# Using Azure ADB2C tokens to authenticate to RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure ADB2C to authenticate my users to a web service. I also us custom policies to enrich the token generated by Azure ADB2C. This works fine.

Now I would like to add another service and for this I would like to use RabbitMq. To authenticate the users to the RabbitMq server, I would like to use RabbitMq's [oauth2 plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-oauth2).

Basically I want to use the same jwt token that Azure ADB2C generates to authenticate&authorize users to the RabbitMq server.

For this to work, I need to supply RabbitMq with the [UAA signing key](http://UAA%20signing%20key) that my custom Azure ADB2C policy is using.

This is an example from the RabbitMq oauth2:

```
[
  %% ...
  %% backend configuration
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2, [
    {resource_server_id, <<"my_rabbit_server">>},
    %% UAA signing key configuration
    {key_config, [
      {signing_keys, #{
        <<"a-key-ID">> => {pem, <<"*-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2dP+vRn+Kj+S/oGd49kq
6+CKNAduCC1raLfTH7B3qjmZYm45yDl+XmgK9CNmHXkho9qvmhdksdzDVsdeDlhK
IdcIWadhqDzdtn1hj/22iUwrhH0bd475hlKcsiZ+oy/sdgGgAzvmmTQmdMqEXqV2
B9q9KFBmo4Ahh/6+d4wM1rH9kxl0RvMAKLe+daoIHIjok8hCO4cKQQEw/ErBe4SF
2cr3wQwCfF1qVu4eAVNVfxfy/uEvG3Q7x005P3TcK+QcYgJxav3lictSi5dyWLgG
QAvkknWitpRK8KVLypEj5WKej6CF8nq30utn15FQg0JkHoqzwiCqqeen8GIPteI7
VwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----*">>}
          }}
      ]}
    ]}
].
```

But I cannot find this "PUBLIC KEY".

For example, looking at this [demo key](https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_edit_profile/discovery/v2.0/keys), there is no PUBLIC KEY as required by the RabbitMq oauth2 authenticator.

Where can I find the PUBLIC KEY of the Azure ADB2C custom policy that I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Azure Portal, AAD B2C Blade. Find your Custom Policy or User Flow. Click the "Run Now" button.
In the pane, you will find the [Open ID Connect Metadata document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#validate-the-id-token).

`https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/your-policy-id/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

In this document you will find a JWKS URI. Open the JWKS URI. In the JWKS URI you will find the parameters used to generate the signing key - modulus (n) and exponent (e).

You need to combine these values (binary encoded bytes) to recreate the public cert that you are looking for.
[I have a RSA public key exponent and modulus. How can I encrypt a string using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094108/i-have-a-rsa-public-key-exponent-and-modulus-how-can-i-encrypt-a-string-using-p)

Comment: Can't manage to make it work. I keep getting this error: "Authentication using an OAuth 2/JWT token failed: signature_invalid". This means that somehow I am not constructing the public key in the right way.

Comment: Most likely. You should probably raise a separate question for that in the cryptography section.

Comment: @Copiltembel how did you provide scope for rabbiMQ users in Azure?