# RSA Modulus and Exponent to OpenSSL pem Format

Tags: php, rsa

I have a RSA Public Key in this format:

```
OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=9ee9f82dd8429d9fa7f091c1d375b9c289bcf2c39ec57e175a2998b4bdd083465ef0fe6c7955c821b7e883929d017a9164a60290f1622f664a72096f5d2ffda7c7825c3d657c2d13d177445fa6cdd5d68b96346006a96040f5b09baae56d0c3efeaa77d57602f69018f5cefd60cb5c71b6b6f8a4b0472e8740367266917d8c13,publicExponent=10001}
```

So, I have the modulus and the exponent.
How can I convert this in a format that is accepted by `openssl_encrypt()` in PHP?
I have searched on Google and didn't find anything good. Isn't there an easy way to format it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `openssl_public_encrypt()` instead of `openssl_encrypt()`, then try this (using phpseclib 1.0):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php')
include('Math/BigInteger.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(array(
    'n' => new Math_BigInteger('9ee9f82dd8429d9fa7f091c1d375b9c289bcf2c39ec57e175a2998b4bdd083465ef0fe6c7955c821b7e883929d017a9164a60290f1622f664a72096f5d2ffda7c7825c3d657c2d13d177445fa6cdd5d68b96346006a96040f5b09baae56d0c3efeaa77d57602f69018f5cefd60cb5c71b6b6f8a4b0472e8740367266917d8c13', 16),
    'e' => new Math_BigInteger('10001', 16)
));

echo $rsa;
```

Altho that said, if you're gonna use phpseclib to convert the key, why not use it to encrypt whatever it is that you're trying to encrypt as well?:

```
//$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$rsa->encrypt('plaintext');
```

Comment: You seem to have one too many zeros in your exponent value (1048577 vs 65537), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Im trying it at the moment with phpseclib 1.0 because 2.0 dont really want to work on my machine.

Comment: The problem is that I get a different encrypted String everytime I encrypt the same string with the same mod and exponent

Comment: @Introser - the ciphertext's are _supposed_ to be different each time. Quoting https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#section-7.2.1 , one of the steps is to "_generate an octet string PS of length k - mLen - 3 consisting of pseudo-randomly generated nonzero octets_". It's done to prevent known plaintext attacks.

Comment: @Introser - I've updated my post to use phpseclib 1.0 code.

Comment: Thats great, had the same Code. The Problem is, at the other end, an android app, im using rsa too. But Java always generate the same string and the result is always a 199 long string, while php generates 256 long different strings

Comment: @Introser - that's a fundamentally different question than the one you asked in this topic. I'd recommend creating a new question to ask about that. And post the code that you're using.

Answer (score -2):

No, there isn't any way to do this. Public/private keys can only be used in **asymmetric** cryptography. `openssl_encrypt()` requires **symmetric** cryptography.

`openssl_public_encrypt()` which you need for asymmetric cryptography wants a pubic key resource. This can be obtained using `openssl_pkey_get_public()`.

Now, `openssl_pkey_get_public()` needs a PEM file. The [docs describe](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php) it as:

> 1. an X.509 certificate resource
> 2. a string having the format file://path/to/file.pem. The named file must contain a PEM encoded certificate/public key (it may contain both).
> 3. A PEM formatted public key.

So you need to create a PEM file from the public key configuration you have in your question. The modulus and exponent you have are enough to do this.

There are several examples on the internet on how to archive this. Have a look at:

- [Generate .pem RSA public key file using base 10 modulus and exponent?](https://superuser.com/questions/1200612/generate-pem-rsa-public-key-file-using-base-10-modulus-and-exponent)
- rawrsa (https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/rawrsa)
- [how to convert raw modulus & exponent to RSA public key (.pem format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568570/how-to-convert-raw-modulus-exponent-to-rsa-public-key-pem-format)

Basically you need to create a "ASN1-formatted text file" and employ some openssl commands.